# Android Authentication scheme ntlm not supported

Tags: android

I am using asynhttpClient for basic authentication

http://loopj.com/android-async-http/

that is looj lib..

below is my code:

usernameRandomPassword = userName + ":" + password;

```
            Log.d("username=",usernameRandomPassword);
            Log.d("url=",url);
            String authorization = "Basic " + Base64.encodeToString(usernameRandomPassword.getBytes("UTF-8"), Base64.NO_WRAP);
            httpClient.addHeader("Authorization",authorization);
            httpClient.addHeader("Content-type", "application/json");
            httpClient.setTimeout(20000);

            httpClient.get( url, new AsyncHttpResponseHandler() {

                    @Override
                    public void onStart() {
                        System.out.println("on satrt");
                        super.onStart();
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(int statusCode, Header[] headers, byte[] responseBody) {

                        System.out.println("on onSuccess statusCode="+statusCode);
                        toastmessgae("onSuccess status code="+statusCode);
                        super.onSuccess(statusCode, headers, responseBody);
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(int statusCode, Header[] headers, byte[] responseBody, Throwable error) {

                        System.out.println("on onFailure="+statusCode);
                        toastmessgae("onFailure status code="+statusCode);
                        super.onFailure(statusCode, headers, responseBody, error);

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onFinish() {
                        System.out.println("on onFinish");
                        super.onFinish();
                    }
                });



        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {

        }
```

but i always receive in console 401, below are logs

**Authentication scheme ntlm not supported.

Unable to respond to any of these challenges: {ntlm=WWW-Authenticate: NTLM, negotiate=WWW-Authenticate: Negotiate}**

The credentials are correct i checked on direct link.

I have spent already a complete day on this, can any one help me?
If you share some example,it will be really helpful.

Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 10, accepted):

here is the answer through code:

add below code to your android file

```
            DefaultHttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            // register ntlm auth scheme
            httpclient.getAuthSchemes().register("ntlm", new NTLMSchemeFactory());
            httpclient.getCredentialsProvider().setCredentials(
                    // Limit the credentials only to the specified domain and port
                    new AuthScope(AuthScope.ANY_HOST, AuthScope.ANY_PORT),
                    // Specify credentials, most of the time only user/pass is needed
                    new NTCredentials(username, password, "", "")
            );

            HttpUriRequest httpget = new HttpGet(your_URL);
            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httpget);
            String responseBody = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());
            Log.i(tag,"responseBody =>>>>>>>>>>"+responseBody);
```

now download lib and java file from

https://github.com/masconsult/android-ntlm

and copy jcifs-1.3.17.jar to your lib folder and
JCIFSEngine and NTLMSchemeFactory to your package. (you can change package if you want..)

Thats it your app is ready to run.

More useful Links:

http://www.developergarden.com/en/marketplace/components/details/cmp/android-ntlm-authentication/

Comment: Link doesn't work. Plus I am getting `getAuthSchemes()` is undefined for HttpClient.

Comment: I removed             httpclient.getAuthSchemes().register("ntlm", new NTLMSchemeFactory()); and it works fine. So I didn't need to add the library or  NTLMSchemeFactory class

Comment: @Hamid how will it respond to the NTLM auth challenge then? Are you sure you are doing it with a webservice which doesn't require NTLM?

Comment: @Sufian Sorry, my previous comment was added accidentally. No, I'm not sure if it was using NTLM or not.

Comment: @Hamid no NTLM was required for sure then. Haven't heard Facebook requiring NTLM. It's only required with Sharepoint of Microsoft (or maybe with some other products of Microsoft).

Comment: gettting 401 exception can you please help me

Comment: I'm gettting 401 exception too. Can you please help me?

Comment: @MiloRambaldi if you find the solution please let me know thanks.

Comment: I found it. It was the domain name that I forgot.  I asked the backend developer :) 

`new NTCredentials(username, password, "", "domain")`

Comment: @MiloRambaldi can you please share your sample code through mail how you did I tried but still no luck

Comment: @alex its same as above. I've done nothing different

Answer (score 1):

Looks to me that you are possibly behind a proxy?  NTLM looks to be a largely undocumented Microsoft protocol:

http://www.innovation.ch/personal/ronald/ntlm.html

You cannot simply use Basic Auth because this is some different authentication scheme required by the server to whom you are speaking, or by a proxy in between you and your destination.

Comment: Thanks for quick response.. Do you have any example for same?

Answer (score 0):

I have same problem. I want to use android asynk http, but i not found ntlm auth
I found solution:
1)use above answer,download and import jcifs-1.3.17.jar
2)then i download https://github.com/loopj/android-async-http  (not JAR file) and import in my project,
3) then in file AsynkHttpClient.java 
after

```
  httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient(cm, httpParams);
```

insert

```
 httpClient.getAuthSchemes().register("ntlm", new NTLMSchemeFactory());
    httpClient.getCredentialsProvider().setCredentials(
            // Limit the credentials only to the specified domain and port
            new AuthScope(AuthScope.ANY_HOST, AuthScope.ANY_PORT),
            // Specify credentials, most of the time only user/pass is needed
           new NTCredentials("username", "pass","", "")


    );
```

!!!!!!! then very important
you must comment like this

```
 httpClient.addRequestInterceptor(new HttpRequestInterceptor() {
            @Override
            public void process(final HttpRequest request, final HttpContext context) throws HttpException, IOException {
                AuthState authState = (AuthState) context.getAttribute(ClientContext.TARGET_AUTH_STATE);
                CredentialsProvider credsProvider = (CredentialsProvider) context.getAttribute(
                        ClientContext.CREDS_PROVIDER);
                HttpHost targetHost = (HttpHost) context.getAttribute(ExecutionContext.HTTP_TARGET_HOST);

//                if (authState.getAuthScheme() == null) {
//                    AuthScope authScope = new AuthScope(targetHost.getHostName(), targetHost.getPort());
//                    Credentials creds = credsProvider.getCredentials(authScope);
//                    if (creds != null) {
//                        authState.setAuthScheme(new BasicScheme());
//                        authState.setCredentials(creds);
//                    }
//                }
            }
        }, 0);
```

that all you need :)

Answer (score 0):

here is the full fledged working for this.

```
try
  {
     DefaultHttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();

  // register ntlm auth scheme
     httpclient.getAuthSchemes().register("ntlm", new NTLMSchemeFactory());

     httpclient.getCredentialsProvider().setCredentials(
             new AuthScope(AuthScope.ANY_HOST, AuthScope.ANY_PORT),
             new NTCredentials("username","password"));

             //xx = ip address yy = port
     HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost("http://xx.xx.xx.xx:yy/");

     Log.e(TAG, "executing request" + httpPost.getRequestLine());
     HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httpPost);

     HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();

     Log.e(TAG, "" + response.getStatusLine());
     if (entity != null)
     {
        Log.e(TAG, "Response content length: " + entity.getContentLength());
     }
     if (entity != null)
     {
        Log.e(TAG, "Response stream: " + getMessage(entity.getContent()));
        entity.consumeContent();
     }

  }
  catch (Exception e)
  {
     Log.e(TAG, "" + e.getMessage());
  }
```

please note to include these imports only

```
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.auth.AuthScope;
import org.apache.http.auth.NTCredentials;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.impl.auth.NTLMSchemeFactory;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
```

and do use httpclient-android-4.3.5.1.jar only.